# What is diff between WindowsFormsSynchronization and DispatcherSynchronization?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

Pro Please let me know diff between **WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext** and **DispatcherSynchronizationContext** ? Dose these belong to *System.Threading* and *System.Windows.Threading* Classes !

Comment: I don't know what they are really for but did you read their documentations first?

Comment: `Dispatcher` is a WPF concept. it has nothing to do with winforms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext** - Provides synchronization in Windows Forms

**DispatcherSynchronizationContext** - WPF application uses 2 threads. One thread is background thread for rendering and the other thread is for UI. So UI elements in one thread are not accessible to other UI threads. So Microsoft introduced the dispatcher which is responsible for multiple UI threads interaction.

DispatcherObject class provides two methods.

1. CheckAccess: It determines whether the calling thread has access to this object. And returns true if the calling thread has access to this object otherwise it returns false.
2. VerifyAccess: It throws InvalidOperationException if the calling thread doesn’t have access to the object.

Comment: Gun ! Thanks for Your Explanation ! Its Short and Best ! and here is the [link](http://www.albahari.com) which help me lot to understand Synchronization lot more !

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.windowsformssynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

this sits in the System.Windows.Forms namespace. This provides a synchronization context for the Windows forms model.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

This sits in the System.Windows.Threading namespace and provides a synchronization context for the WPF model

remember - Winforms and WPF are different in that WPF is a new platform for doing desktop client apps and somewhat "replaces" the classic Winforms model.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is entirely in private implementation details.  They are the corresponding implementation of `SynchronizationContext` for each relevant paradigm.  There is never any reason to access either object by their direct type; you should only ever need to treat either of them as an arbitrary `SynchronizationContext`.